# Inconsistent Crash with PJSIP 2.13 in iOS App on Launch: "pjsua_0 (14): signal SIGABRT at pj_mutex_lock"

Tags: ios, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm facing an issue with an iOS app developed in Xcode 15.0.1, incorporating PJSIP (version 2.13) for phone call functionality. The app is targeted for iOS 17.1.1. My project setup includes the necessary header and library search paths:

Header Search Paths:
./pjproject-2.13/pjmedia/include

./pjproject-2.13/pjlib/include

./pjproject-2.13/pjsip/include

./pjproject-2.13/pjnath/include

./pjproject-2.13/pjlib-util/include

Library Search Paths:

./pjproject-2.13/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios-swift/Libraries

All the .a files from PJProject are correctly referenced in my project.

Issue: The app crashes on one specific device immediately after launch, with the error pjsua_0 (14): signal SIGABRT at pj_mutex_lock. The crash occurs after the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method returns true. This issue does not manifest on other devices, even though they run the same version of iOS.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

1 Verified header and library search paths.

2 Ensured all PJProject .a files are correctly referenced.

3 Tested on multiple devices running iOS 17.1.1.

I am seeking insights into the cause of this crash. It appears to be device-specific, but it's unclear why it's happening, especially since the iOS version is consistent across devices.

Any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve or further diagnose this issue would be greatly appreciated.